# Javascript Store as a variable comma separated strings for mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using nodeJS with MongoDB. I'm trying to query the DB and add `populate` like the doc says:

```
Story
.findOne({ title: /timex/i })
.populate('_creator', 'name')
```

The thing is, I need to use `'_creator', 'name'` several times. How can I store this at the start of my file so that I can use it multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EMCAScript6, you can use an array as a parameter list using the [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

At the beginning of the file, you can make an array:

```
const params = ['_creator', 'name']
```

And then reference it throughout your code as:

```
Story
.findOne({ title: /timex/i })
.populate(...params)
```